# Run as different user switch user for whole PC

Tags: windows-7

I'm facing a problem with the feature-run as different user.
I have few runas shortcuts for programs which needs to be run under different user. The problem is, that it automatically switch the user also for all my other programs also for those which are already running.

I'm not sure if it is a bug or it should really work like this.
If I run after runas program with my normal account it doesn't help and I have to reset whole PC or wait like 10 or more minutes till the things get into normal.

It looks like it influence also other running programs, the second account does not have rights for internet, and if I run some program under this second account it blocks the internet for my normal user.

My runas shortcuts look like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:domain\acc.adm "WScript C:\Scripts\Reset-Password.vbs" – reset script

C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:domain\acc.adm "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE C:\Scripts\WILMA_Template.xltm" - excel template

C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:domain\acc.adm "mmc dsa.msc" – Active Directory
```

Is there any possibility to run programs as different users in some sandbox or virtual mode ?
I'm using W7 and W10.
Thank you.

Comment: Run as different user does not influence currently running programs. In fact you can't easily switch the user context of a running program. What does your runas shortcut actually look like and what does it invoke?

Comment: Hi, well it looks like it influence also other running programs, the second account does not have rights for internet, and if I run some program under this second account it blocks the internet for my normal user. My runas shortcuts looks like this : 
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:domain\testacc "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE C:\Scripts\WILMA_Template.xltm" - excel template
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /savecred /user:domain\testacc "mmc dsa.msc" – Active Directory

Comment: Don't put such stuff in a comment. Add it to your question, it's additional, relevant information.

Comment: ok added to the main question

Comment: The idea was to make it readable. The parts added the question contain a different user. They don't seem unusual though. What do you mean it blocks internet access for your normal user? Depending on how the block is implemented it might be blocking the whole machine. Why do you assume it's switching the user context for currently running processes as well?

Comment: To make this clear, My normal account has rights to browse the internet, however the second account is not allowed to do it. After I run for example active directory under the second account it switch also for other programs, so after my browser keeps saying that this user is not allowed to access this page, but the browser was started under my normal account.